# Can not set ref to input and use nextTick focus in loop component vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I can not set `:ref="type"` to input. This is my loop, I use Vue components

```
<b-tr style="white-space: nowrap;" v-for="i in 8" :key="i">
    <input-my-form  :limit="i" :value="100"></input-my-form>
</b-tr>
```

This input is in components. This is my props data **:**

`props: ["limit", "value"],`

```
<input :ref="'type'+limit"  v-on:keyup.enter="nextFocus(limit)" placeholder="xxx" v-model.number="value" />
```

I try to use this script methods **:**

```
nextFocus(limit) {
  let re = limit +1
  let ref = 'type'+re
  console.log(ref ,this.$refs[ref])
  if(this.$refs[ref] != undefined){
      var el = this.$refs[ref];
      this.$nextTick(() => {
          el.focus();
      })
  }
}
```

when I enter in `console.log` It undefined my ref and not focus when I enter input.

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: What do you mean by `v-for="i in 8"` ? v-for directive is used to loop over a data usually an array or object but in your post it just a number.

Comment: Looping on a number is totally fine and I guess it's for example purposes. Not sure what you're doing with the whole `let ref = 'type'+re` part because you could to this during the creation of the component itself. But if you want to access a `$ref` inside of a component, you should at first target the component with a `$ref` so it would be like `this.$refs.inputMyForm.$refs.type5` or alike.

Comment: @kissu thank sir i will try it